# Sync views with offset

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Assigning the same view to multiple OpenLayers maps result in synchronized views which update across maps (e.g. when user pans or zooms).
I want to have the view of maps synchronized, but with an offset. Is this still possible by re-using a view across the maps? Or do I have to handle the events myself?

And what is the difference between using the same view versus using the `bindTo` method as described in the OpenLayers docs (https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch03-charting-the-map-class/example-05.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindTo` was removed in version 3.5.0 (current version is 4.6.4). So using it would force you to use an 2+ years old version of OpenLayers.

One-way binding on the other hand can easily be achieved with event listeners.

Two-way binding is quite difficult to achive, because you have to make sure not to create update-loops. If you place change listeners on both maps, they would repeatedly call each other.

You can easily offset the center position of the second map by fiddling with the event value.

```js
var view = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0], zoom: 2
});
var view2 = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0], zoom: 2
});
var source = new ol.source.OSM();

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: source
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view
});
var map2 = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map2',
  view: view2
});

function updateView(event, viewRef){
  let newValue = event.target.get(event.key);

  if(event.key === 'center') {
    // we need to transform the value, it comes in the wrong projection
    newValue = ol.proj.transform(newValue , source.getProjection(), 'EPSG:3857');
    // offset the value somehow here
  }
  viewRef.set(event.key, newValue);
}

view.on('change:resolution', function(event){
  updateView(event, view2);
});

view.on('change:center', function(event){
  updateView(event, view2);
});
```

```css
  .map{
    max-height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="map2" class="map"></div>
```